# Using impersonation for checking user in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages, impersonation

I have web application written in asp.net where I checked name of user by this simple code:

```
            string[] userName = Context.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].Split('\\');
            try {
                LabelUserName.Text = userName[1];
                LabelUserName.Visible = true;
                HiddenField1.Value = userName[1];
                ViewState["UserName"] = userName[1];
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Cannot impersonate user: " + error.ToString());
                LabelUserName.Text = "UNKNOWN";
                LabelUserName.Visible = true;
                
            }
```

I try to rewrite this web application using Razor Pages with newest .net core, but I'm little confused:

1. how add this code in _Layout (this is my assume - before that this code was in MasterPage - it's global for all pages - or maybe there is another way?)?
2. is maybe better way to get this functionality? I need to get windows login for user viewing application.

Comment: Are you using razor page or mvc in .net core?

Comment: I'm using Razor Page

Answer (score 0):

Common code will be moved to a base class (basepagemodel in case of razor page) and basepagemodel class should inherited from PageModel like as below:

```
public class BasePageModel : PageModel
{
     public bool UserInfo
    {
        get
        {
            // play with httprequest and extract user login name, accesstoken, etc and perform validation according to your requirement
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.Cookies["accesstoken"]);
        }
    }
    
    // another method
}

public class indexModel : BasePageModel
{
        // request handling here
}
```

Set basepagemodel as model for shared layout page(_Layout) as below:

```
@model Application.BasePageModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=EDGE" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
<environment include="Development,Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/jquery-ui/dist/css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</environment>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
        <a>
             <strong>
               @{
                  <span style="margin-right:-2px;">Welcome</span>
                  if (Model.UserInfo)
                       {
                           <span>User Logged in</span>
                       }
                    }
              </strong>
         </a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I should create it by my own? I reached some documentation and used _ViewStart.cshtml as base for that kind of things.